# 1C Bitrix - Override CIBlockPropertyDate method

Tags: php, bitrix

I need to override `CIBlockPropertyDate` method for one component. I mean, I need to get what I want in one form, but leave the default behavior in other situations.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Create a class and extend it from `CIBlockPropertyDate`?

Comment: Um, yeah, but where should I place it?

Comment: I suppose it should be `/bitrix/php_interface/`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Composer to autoload your classes.

In Bitrix you can place it in `/local/` folder, for example under `/local/lib/` folder.

Your `/local/composer.json` file should look like this:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "YourNamespace\\": "lib/YourNamespace"
        }
    }
}
```

Your custom classes should be placed under YourNamespace namespace in `/local/lib/YourNamespace/` folder.

Your autoload file should be included in `init.php`:

```
<?php
// file /local/php_interface/init.php
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/local/vendor/autoload.php';
```

And don't forget to run `composer install` from `/local/` folder to generate classmaps